# lcm and polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the polynomials:
$p\left(x\right)=x^3-6x^2+14x-15$
$q\left(x\right)=x^3-8x^2+21x-18$
the LCM is :
$d\left(x\right)=\left(x-3\right)^2\left(x-2\right)\left(x^2-3x+5\right)$
I'm trying to figure out how to find:
$d(x)=a(x)*p(x)+b(x)*q(x)$
I need something like Euclidean algorithm but for LCM not GCD.
Thank you

Comment: Since $d$ is a multiple of $p,q$ we may just choose e.g. $a=d/p$ and $b=0$. Of course we can also apply the euclidean algorithm here since the GCD always divides the LCM

Comment: If we calculate the algorithm to GCD we get :
$\bigg(-\frac{2}{15} x + \frac{3}{5}\bigg)\bigg(x^{3} - 6 x^{2} + 14 x - 15\bigg) + \bigg(\frac{2}{15} x - \frac{1}{3}\bigg)\bigg(x^{3} - 8 x^{2} + 21 x - 18\bigg) = x - 3$
How can this help?
(sorry if the question sounds silly I try to understand)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in any Euclidean domain, you simply add one step to the *extended Euclidean* algorithm: all remainders  in the Euclidean algorithm satisfy a Bézout's relation $r_k=u_kp+v_kq$, with coprime coefficients $u_k,v_k$ calculated recursively.

The g.c.d. is the last nonzero remainder $r_n$, so  $d=u_np+v_nq$. Proceeding one step further, the remainder is $0$, and we obtain $\; 0=u_{n+1}p+v_{n+1}q$,  so that the l.c.m. (defined up to a unit factor) is
$$\operatorname{lcm}(p,q)=u_{n+1}p=-v_{n+1}q .$$

*Added*: Here is how it goes with your example.

$$\begin{array}{rccl}
r_k(x) & u_k & v_k & Q_k(x) \\ \hline
p(x) & 1 & 0 \\
q(x) & 0 & 1 & Q_1=1 \\ \hline
r_1=2x^2-7x+3 & 1 & -1 &  Q_2=\frac14(2x-9) \\
r_2=\frac{15}4(x-3) & -Q_2 & 1+Q_2 & Q_3=\frac 4{15}(2x-1) \\
r_3=0 & 1+Q_2Q_3 & -1-(1+Q_2)Q_3
\end{array}$$
Therefore, we obtain both that $\gcd\bigl(p(x),q(x)\bigr)=\color{red}{x-3}$ (we simplify by the factor $\frac{15}4$, which is a unit in the polynomial ring), and \begin{align}
\operatorname{lcm}\bigl(p(x),q(x)\bigr)&=\bigl(1+\tfrac14(2x-9)\tfrac4{15}(2x-1)\bigr)(x^3-6x^2+14x-15) \\
&= \tfrac 4{15}(\underbrace{x^2-5x+6}_{(x-2)(x-3)})(\underbrace{x^3-6x^2+14x-15}_{(x-3)(x^2-3x+5)}) \\[1ex]
&=\tfrac 4{15}\color{blue}{(x-2)(x-3)^2(x^2-3x+5)}
\end{align}

Comment: maybe there is a chance for an explanation with the example I wrote?
I could not understand how do i find $\operatorname{lcm}(p,q)=u_{n+1}p=-v_{n+1}q .$

Comment: @NFLX: I've added the algorithm with your example. I hope it is clear enough.

Comment: Thank you very much it helped me a lot :)